# Matrix Multiplication ¿logic error in cicle? (C++ OOP)

Tags: c++, matrix, multiplication

I'm trying to write a code for multiply matrixes, the general problem its in the moment when the "for" cicles try to change the value of the resultant matrix(C).

if you try to execute this code, introducing 2 matrixes A & B, both 2x2, you will see in results that the resultant matrix C, only shows the first value, C[0][0].

I've already try to verify the method "mult(Matriz A, Matriz B)", but somethings gotta be wrong, could you please help me find whats wrong in cicle.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 10

using namespace std;

class Matriz
{
private:
    int M[TAM][TAM];
    int n, m;


public:
    Matriz ()
    {
        n = m = 1;
    }

    Matriz (int n, int m)
    {
        this->n = n;
        this->m = m;
    }

    void ingMatriz(char c)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
            {
                cout<<c<<"["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"]=";
                cin >>M[i][j];
            }
    }

    void muestraMatriz()
    {
        for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cout << "\n";
            for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
                cout<<"   "<<M[i][j];
        }
    }

    void mult (Matriz A, Matriz B)
    {
        int an=A.n;
        int am=A.m;
        int bm=B.m;


        for(int a=0; a<an; a++) //This is the general cicle
            for(int b=0; b<bm; b++)
                for(int c=0; c<am; c++)
                    M[a][b] += (A.M[a][c] * B.M[c][b]);
    }

};

int main()
{
    cout << "\nxxxxxx Multiplicacion de matrices xxxxxx";

    int f1,c1,f2,c2;

    cout<< "\n \n* El numero de columnas de la 1er matriz(A) debe ser igual a numero de filas de la segunda matriz(B) *";
    cout<< "\n \nIngresa el numero de FILAS de la 1er matriz(A): ";
    cin >> f1;
    cout<< "\nIngresa el numero de COLUMNAS de la 1er matriz(A): ";
    cin >> c1;
    cout<< "\nIngresa el numero de FILAS de la 2da matriz(B): ";
    cin >> f2;
    cout<< "\nIngresa el numero de COLUMNAS de la 2da matriz(B): ";
    cin >> c2;

    if (c1==f2)
    {
        Matriz A(f1,c1);
        cout << "\nIngresa los valores de la matriz 'A': \n\n";
        A.ingMatriz('A');
        Matriz B(f1,c2);
        cout << "\n \n********************************************\nIngresa los valores de la matriz 'B': \n \n";
        B.ingMatriz('B');

        Matriz C;
        C.mult(A,B);
        cout << "\nMatriz A: ";
        A.muestraMatriz();
        cout << "\nMatriz B: ";
        B.muestraMatriz();
        cout << "\nMultiplicacion AB: ";
        C.muestraMatriz();
    }
    else
        cout << "\n \n \n El numero de columnas de la 1er matriz(A) debe ser igual al numero de filas de la segunda matriz(B) ";

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
};
```

I changed just a few things in main, as you can see in the picture, i changed the object C, to Matriz C(f1,c2), so it could set the values for the resultant matrix, but stills showing garbage. Heres a picture of the output:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTdK7.png

FINAL CODE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#define TAM 10   

using namespace std;   

class Matriz
{
      private: 
               int M[TAM][TAM];
               int n, m;
      public:
             Matriz ():n(1), m(1)
             {
                 for (int i=0; i<TAM; i++)
                 for (int j=0; j<TAM; j++)
                 M[i][j] = 0;
             }

             Matriz (int n, int m):n(n), m(m)
             {
                 for (int i=0; i<TAM; i++)
                 for (int j=0; j<TAM; j++)
                 M[i][j] = 0;
             }
             void ingMatriz(char c)
             {
               for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
                  for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
                     {
                      cout<<c<<"["<<i+1<<"]["<<j+1<<"]=";
                      cin >> M[i][j];
                     }
             }  

            void muestraMatriz()
            {
               for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
                 {
                  cout << "\n";
                  for (int j=0; j<m; j++)
                  cout<<"   "<<M[i][j];
                 }
             }   

             void mult (Matriz A, Matriz B)
             {
                  int an=A.n;
                  int am=A.m;
                  int bm=B.m;

               for(int a=0; a<an; a++)
                   for(int b=0; b<bm; b++)
                       for(int c=0; c<am; c++)                                    
                           M[a][b] += (A.M[a][c] * B.M[c][b]);             
              }
};

int main()
{
    while (0<1){
    cout << "xxxxxx Multiplicacion de matrices xxxxxx";
    int f1,c1,f2,c2;

    cout<< "\n \n* El numero de columnas de la 1er matriz(A) debe ser igual al numero de filas de la segunda matriz(B) *";

    cout<< "\n \nIngresa el numero de FILAS de la 1er matriz(A): ";
    cin >> f1;

    cout<< "\nIngresa el numero de COLUMNAS de la 1er matriz(A): ";
    cin >> c1;

    cout<< "\nIngresa el numero de FILAS de la 2da matriz(B): ";
    cin >> f2;

    cout<< "\nIngresa el numero de COLUMNAS de la 2da matriz(B): ";
    cin >> c2;

    if (c1==f2)
    {
    Matriz A(f1,c1);    
    cout << "\nIngresa los valores de la matriz 'A': \n\n";
    A.ingMatriz('A');
    Matriz B(f2,c2);

cout << "\n \n********************************************\nIngresa los valores de la matriz 'B': \n \n";
B.ingMatriz('B');
Matriz C(f1,c2);
C.mult(A,B);
cout << "\n\nMatriz A: ";
A.muestraMatriz();
cout << "\n\nMatriz B: ";
B.muestraMatriz();
cout << "\n\nMultiplicacion AB: ";
C.muestraMatriz();
}
else
cout << "\n \n \n El numero de columnas de la 1er matriz(A) debe ser igual al numero de filas de la segunda matriz(B) ";
getchar();
getchar();
system("cls");
}
return 0;
};
```

Comment: I think it's because you never set n and m for ' this'  resulting matrix

Comment: Mmm, i tried to change 
Matriz C(f1,c2);
    C.mult(A,B);

f1 = A matrix total rows
c2 = B matrix total colums

Now it shows all the resultant matrix, but the contents still being trash.


f1 = A matrix rows

Comment: Can you post the output as well?

Comment: Of course, its now in the post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little tricky for me to tell what your main function is doing because I'm not a native Spanish speaker =)

But the problem looks to be the fact that you're initializing C using the default constructor, which initializes its width and height both to one. Then, when you try to multiply the other two 2 * 2 matrices, the indices you multiply never go over 1 and 1 - even though A and B both have `n = 2` and `m = 2`, since C only has `n = m = 1` (as assigned in its constructor), it only multiplies the first element, then exits both loops.

In order to get what you want, you need to initialize C to the proper dimensions first like so:

`Matriz C(2, 2)`

However, that could get annoying pretty quick, since you already know what the output matrix's size should be - so, in your matrix multiplication code, you could set `m = A.m` and `n = B.n` respectively, since the resultant matrix of the multiplication is supposed to have width of 1st matrix and height of 2nd. Then you just have to make sure you're passing in matrices of the right size when you multiply =)

Second problem I see is that you're not initializing the values of C to anything before you do the multiplication - in essence you're doing the multiplication properly, but since you have uninitialized values in there already, when you add the multiplication on, garbage + x = more garbage. EDIT: accidental post before done. What you want is to change the line `M[a][b] += (A.M[a][c] * B.M[c][b]);` to `M[a][b] = (A.M[a][c] * B.M[c][b]);` - that way you properly set the value to what it should be, instead of adding on to whatever was already there.

EDIT2: Instead of initializing in the multiplication code itself (see comments) you should initialize in the constructors with a loop:

```
public:
    Matriz ():n(1), m(1) //also note the initializer lists instead of doing it in the body of the ctor
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TAM; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; i < TAM; ++j)
                M[i][j] = 0;
    }

    Matriz (int n, int m):n(n), m(m) //lets you do this instead of explicitly dereferencing this (this->n = n, etc) -- 
                                    //also, more efficient generally (though maybe not since your data is only ints in this case anyways)

    {
        for (int i = 0; i < TAM; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; i < TAM; ++j)
                M[i][j] = 0;
    }
```

Comment: I did it, please check the post, i added new information and the output. Thanks

Comment: Well, second problem I see is that you're not initializing the values of C to anything before you do the multiplication - in essence you're doing the multiplication properly, but since you have uninitialized values in there already, when you add the multiplication on, garbage + x = more garbage.

EDIT: accidental post before done. What you want is to change the line `M[a][b] += (A.M[a][c] * B.M[c][b]);` to `M[a][b] = (A.M[a][c] * B.M[c][b]);` - that way you properly set the value to what it should be, instead of adding on to whatever was already there.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that ;)

Comment: The problem of removing the '+' it's that it would set the value just for one multiplication, i would try to explain it with this:

A.n = 2
A.m = 2
B.n = 2
B.m = 2


1st cicle
C[0][0] = A.M[0][0] * B.M[0][0] //OK
2nd cicle
C[0][0] = A.M[0][1] * B.M[1][0] //This is gonna change the value in C[0][0]
3rd cicle
C[0][0] = A.M[0][2] * B.M[2][0] //This is gonna change again the value in C[0][0]
4th cicle
C[0][1] = A.M[0][0] * B.M[0][1] //Past cicles gonna be repeating, overwriting the values and not aading to the actual content. 
Is there a way to start the matrix values on 0? So there's no garbage.

Comment: True that. There are a couple ways I can think of, the best one being just initializing them in the constructors (something you should get in the habit of doing anyways, for specifically this reason). I'll edit my answer to show exact code ;)

Comment: Hopefully this is the whole problem fixed now ^^

Comment: Whooaa thanks for your help! it's now working 
Posted the final code in the main question. Gracias por la ayuda!
Thanks for your help!  :D

Answer (score 0):

Since you are multiplying 2 matrix: A.n = B.m so your code should be more like:

```
void mult (Matriz A, Matriz B)
    {
     for(k=0;k<A.m;k++)
     {
       for(i=0;i<A.n;i++)
       {
        M[i][k] = 0;
        for(j=0;j<B.m;j++)
            M[k][i] += A[k][j] * B[j][i]  
        cout << "Matriz c:" << M[k][i]<<" ";    
       }
        cout <<"\n";
      }
```